# Drupal 8.1.1 - Migrate 3400 INSERT (from sql) to custom content type

Tags: php, drupal, entities, migrate

I need migrate 3400 rows from phpMyAdmin export to a custom content type over Drupal 8.

I tried to do with migration modules but, for example Migrate Plus and Migrate Tools are not compatible with my version of Drupal (8.1.1)

I wanted to import records using a PHP script.

I have tried many things but in many cases I said "undefined function" (by using, for example, entity_create) and more evidence I've done.

Example 1:

```
$new_page_values = array();
$new_page_values['type'] = 'my_content_type';
$new_page_values['title'] = "Titulo";
$new_page_values['path'] = "Path";

$new_page = entity_create('node', $new_page_values);
$new_page->save();
```

Example 2

```
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create(array(
          'type' => 'article',
          'title' => 'The title',
          'langcode' => $language,
          'uid' => 1,
          'status' => 1,
          'body' => array('The body text'),
          'field_date' => array("2000-01-30"),
            //'field_fields' => array('Custom values'), // Add your custon field values like this
    ));
$node->save();
```

Example 3:

```
db_insert('example_entity')
    ->fields(array(
      'type' => $entity->getEntityTypeId(),
      'id' => $entity->id(),
      'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
      'updated' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ))
    ->execute();
```

I'm trying to run a .php file from the server console (php updateData.php)

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Examples are published on Question.

Answer (score 0):

Javier, the migration in D8 is still a WIP.

My advise:

- install the latest Drupal 8.1,
- install the latest modules for **migrate_tools**, **migrate_plus**, **migrate_source_csv** and **migrate_source_json**. Preferably the latest beta-versions.
- change your phpAdmin output to a csv-file.

Perhaps you need to create your custom entity. Migrate_tools has 2 examples for the migration. It also contains a csv example. The migration-process should seamlessly import your stuff.

> **Tips:** YAML-files are extremely sensitive for grammatics such as spaces. And you shouldn't have to identify an external/migration database. But remember, what ever worked yesterday, today may be different. I am working on my migration for the last 6 months.

Migration process is a completely different story then the D7 one.

**Edited:** install Drush 8. Use Composer for the easy way. Drush is needed to run the migration script from commandline, manifest is obsolete.

**Edited 2:** IMO the best explanation for and why using the D8 migration.
Look at this site https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2016/05/04/using-the-new-drupal-8-migration-api-module.html. Your wish to use your own PHP seems mainly because you can't seem to use D8's migration?